# Package structure - how to avoid duplicate file and object names

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-module

When I develop my Python programs, I like to keep each class in its own `.py` file. This makes life easier and keeps my projects organized.
Lately, I have started creating Python packages and modules.

Suppose my package structure looks something like this:

```
MyProject
│   setup.py
│
└───project
        __init__.py
        Object1.py
        Object2.py
        Object3.py
```

When each `Object.py` file contains a `class object1`, `class object2` (etc.) inside of it.

When importing the objects from the package, I would have to use the rather ugly statement `import project.object1.object1`, or `from project.object1 import object1`.
**I would like to do something like `import project.object1` to import the `object1` class, which is located inside the `Object1.py` file.**

I have searched for a solution in the official docs, but I just can't find it! I'm sure there is a way to make it possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up `__init__.py` and putting package imports in there.

Comment: Note that a file per class  is common for example for Java, but not for Python. You should experiment also to group some related classes per file, or partitioning by sub-system, or whatever, and reduce the number of files you have to manage, to see if you like it.

Comment: This is not to say that your scheme does not work in Python. It certainly does, but is not a common pattern.